# How to change the frequency of a sin based animation smoothly while the animation is running

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader

```
float wave = 0.5f * sin( _Time.w * Frequency + 12.0f) + 1.0f;
```

Even if i change "Frequency" in super small steps (0.001f) the animation tends to jump.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of the phase, because when you change frequency and then multiply by the current time, you have a sudden jump in phase.

Based on the way you currently calculate it:
in your class definition:

```
  float mCurrentPhase = 12.0f; // start phase at 12 for some reason
```

in your function

```
  mCurrentPhase += (Time.deltaTime * Frequency);
  float wave = 0.5f * sin( mCurrentPhase ) + 1.0f;
```

What is the +12.0f for?  Did you want to start the waveform at a certain point?  Because +12.0f is actually going to just start you off in the next period of the sine wave - same as the last one.

Also, sine functions get flakey with really big numbers, and since sine is periodic, you can also do this:

```
  mCurrentPhase += (Time.deltaTime * Frequency);

  // Keep phase between 0 .. 2*PI ... Note not tested in Unity
  if (mCurrentPhase >= 2*PI) mCurrentPhase -= 2*PI; 

  float wave = 0.5f * sin( mCurrentPhase ) + 1.0f;
```